# laravel withCount() Cardinality violation error when relationship is hasMany

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-controller, laravel-models

This is my models:

```
//project model
class Project extends Model {
    .....
    public function items(){
        return $this->hasMany(ProjectItem::class,'project_id');
    }
}
//project items model
class ProjectItem extends Model{
    ...
 public function project(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
}
```

In my controller I want to get the collection with the count of project items
$projects =

```
Project::Select(['id','title'])->Where([            
            ['company' , '=', $company->id]
        ])->withCount('items')->paginate(50);
```

But I get this error :

> SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more
> than 1 row (SQL: select `id`, `title`, (select `id` from
> `project_items` where `projects`.`id` = `project_items`.`project_id`)
> as `items_count` from `projects` where (`company` = 2) limit 50 offset
> 0)

What is the problem here?  Why it doesn't use the SQL COUNT() function in the query, but instead still using SELECT?

I using jetstream inertia , hence will need collection in return. And I also don't want to load the relationship model in the collections as well.

**Edit**

Here is how I create the tables:

```
//projects table
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('company');
            $table->foreign('company')->references('id')->on('company')->onDelete('cascade');//projects is belong to another company table.
            $table->timestamps();
        });

//project_items table
Schema::create('project_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');  
            $table->longText('desc')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('project_id');
            $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

The 'project' itself also belong to 'company' table. But I don't think is relevant since I only query the projects and the project items here .

Sorry because my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

can you replace your query with this and check

```
Project::select('id','title')->where('company' , $company->id)->withCount('items')->paginate(50);
```

Comment: tried but still got the same error

Comment: try to divide the query and check on which condition it's getting error. Is it with withCount.

Comment: Yes, it is the withCount that caused the error. It working fine without the withCount, even with() also works.

Comment: I tried to generate something same but working fine for me. check if your withCount is working fine for other models or not. if not maybe you are using an older mysql version.

Comment: I tried with other models, yes, it is working fine. I also updated the question with the migration i use to create the tables. Not sure if it is relevant.  Thanks

Comment: Ok, found the problem. It was I added the global scope `static::addGlobalScope` in the projectItem model, it will override the Count function. Nevertheless, still thanks for you help.